# What's the syntax for Html.Display()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've got a model like this:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<NewsItem> NewsItems { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalSales { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SalesOrderHeader> SalesInformation { get; set; }

}
```

And in the View I want to do this:

```
<p>@Html.Display(Model.TotalSales)</p>
```

But I'm running into this error:

```
HomeViewModel does not contain a definition for Display"
```

Which is odd because it should be the `Html` type that has `Display`.

What is the correct syntax for what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: you should use @Html.DisplayFor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to use `DisplayFor` (`Display`) fo doing this. If you need to add some display attributes (like only last 2 digits to be shown) you will do this only one time in the `ViewModel`.

```
<p>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TotalSales)</p>
```

If you really want to use `Display`, the MVC is smart enough to render this with your data from `Model`.

```
<p>@Html.Display("TotalSales")</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay it's actually:

```
<p>@Model.TotalSales</p>
```

Solved!